# Как сделать словарь с порядковым номером для каждой буквы алфавита?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Пытаюсь сделать словарь, так чтобы у каждой буквы алфавита был свой порядковый номер.

Проблема в том, что ошибка: `unhashable type: 'list'`

```
str1="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"

alf =[]

for txt in str1:
    
         alf.append(txt) 
    
         d = dict.fromkeys((([i for i in alf]),num for num in range(0,33)))

print(d)
```

Comment: Если ничего не путаю,то в ру алфавите 33 буквы, а range(0,32)))
 последний элемент будет с индексом 31

Comment: В дополнение к ответам от @andy.37 и @MaxU: ```d = {chr(j) : i for i, j in enumerate(range(0x430, 0x450))}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {i: l for i, l in enumerate(str1)} # d = {0: 'а', ...}
```

или

```
d = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(str1)} # d = {'а': 0, ...}
```

А в целом, достаточно (почти всегда) использовать просто `enumerate(str1)`

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [Uicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) в качестве порядкого номера:

```
In [57]: d = {c:ord(c) for c in str1}

In [58]: d
Out[58]:
{'а': 1072,
 'б': 1073,
 'в': 1074,
 'г': 1075,
 'д': 1076,
 'е': 1077,
 'ё': 1105,
 'ж': 1078,
 'з': 1079,
 'и': 1080,
 'й': 1081,
 'к': 1082,
 'л': 1083,
 'м': 1084,
 'н': 1085,
 'о': 1086,
 'п': 1087,
 'р': 1088,
 'с': 1089,
 'т': 1090,
 'у': 1091,
 'ф': 1092,
 'х': 1093,
 'ц': 1094,
 'ч': 1095,
 'ш': 1096,
 'щ': 1097,
 'ъ': 1098,
 'ы': 1099,
 'ь': 1100,
 'э': 1101,
 'ю': 1102,
 'я': 1103}
```